# Nativescript - cannot edit an input field at the bottom of page (iOS)

Tags: nativescript

Have a page with lots of input fields laid out vertically inside a scrollview - some at the bottom.

The problem is when I tap on an input field at the bottom - the keyboard pops up and hides the field - it doesn't auto scroll up to make the field visible.

This is on iOS.

Any help?

Doesn't happen in Android - it automatically makes the input field visible by moving it above the keyboard.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On iOS, you can use [nativescript-iqkeyboardmanage](https://www.npmjs.com/package/nativescript-iqkeyboardmanager)r plugin which resolves this case and makes the content "pushable".

Sample demo demonstrating the usage of the plugin can be found [here](https://github.com/NickIliev/NS-Issues-2018/tree/master/NativeScript/issue_1247).

Comment: Worked like a charm - though I had to do a "pod repo update".